# T-SQL on XML (using XQuery)

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have the below XML

```
<myroot>
<scene>
<sceneId>983247</sceneId>
<item>
<coordinates>
<coordinate>0</coordinate>
<coordinate>1</coordinate>
<coordinate>2</coordinate>
<coordinate>3</coordinate>
</coordinates>
<Values>
<Value>34</Value>
<Value>541</Value>
<Value>255</Value>
<Value>332</Value>
</Values>
</item>
</scene>
</myroot>
```

How can I get using TSQL the following result:

```
Col1 Col2
0    34    
1    541
2    255
3    332
```

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath 2.0 expression:

```
/myroot/scene/item/
   string-join(for $pos in (0 to max(*/count(*)))
               return string-join(for $col in (1 to max(count(*)))
                                  return if ($pos=0)
                                         then concat('Col',$col)
                                         else *[$col]/*[$pos],
                                  ' '),
               '&#xA;')
```

Output:

```
Col1 Col2
0 34
1 541
2 255
3 332
```

Comment: Trying to run it like this:

select  @xml.query('
/myroot/scene/item/ 
   string-join(for $pos in (0 to max(*/count(*))) 
               return string-join(for $col in (1 to max(count(*))) 
                                  return if ($pos=0) 
                                         then concat('Col',$col) 
                                         else *[$col]/*[$pos], 
                                  ' '), 
               '&#xA;')') 

Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @koumides: `fn:count()` must have one argument. The first `fn:max` invocation counts the maximum number of element into some "column". So it must be `max(*/count(*))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my XML noob approach.

If you only trust the element sequencing, and not the coordinate values themselves being a sequence:

```
select
  coordinate  = max(case when element = 'coordinate' then elemval end)
, value       = max(case when element = 'Value' then elemval end)
from (
  select 
    element   = row.value('local-name(.)','varchar(32)')
  , elemval   = row.value('.','int')
  , position  = row.value('for $s in . return count(../*[. << $s]) + 1', 'int')
  from @xml.nodes('/myroot/scene/item/*/*') a (row)
  ) a
group by position
```

Alternatively written as two `.nodes()` and a `JOIN` (you get the idea).

If do you trust the coordinate numbering to be a sequence starting at zero:

```
select 
  coordinate = row.value('for $s in . return count(../*[. << $s]) + 1', 'int')
             - 1
, value      = row.value('.','int')
from @xml.nodes('/myroot/scene/item/Values/*') a (row)
```

If you only trust the coordinate numbering to be a sequence, but from an arbitrary seed:

```
select 
  coordinate = row.value('for $s in . return count(../*[. << $s]) + 1', 'int')
             + row.value('(/myroot/scene/item/coordinates/coordinate)[1]','int')
             - 1
, value      = row.value('.','int')
from @xml.nodes('/myroot/scene/item/Values/*') a (row)
```

Paths can be abbreviated:

- `/myroot/scene/item/*/*` -> `//item/*/*`
- `/myroot/scene/item/Values/*` -> `//Values/*`
- `/myroot/scene/item/coordinates/coordinate` -> `//coordinate`

But I don't know the wisdom of this either way.

`//item/*/*` can probably be made more specific, so that it only includes `coordinate` and `Value` edge nodes, but I don't know the syntax.